# Add a custom Axis label with unique color and size

Tags: r

I have the following chart:

```
df<- data.frame(year=c(1960,1961,1962),value=c(10,18,20))
ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=value))+geom_col()+
geom_hline(yintercept =18,linetype="dashed", color = "red",size=1)
```

[image]

I would like to add a red label in the Y axis with the text "Actual Value" where the red line is.

I know i cann add the text changing breaks, but then i could not have the new text in red.

There is any way I can change only that one's colour and size but not the other legends in the axis?

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `annoate`:

1. Use `annoate` to specify the text you want to plot. Provide `x =`  and `y =`  arguments to indicate where to plot.
2. Use `coord_cartesian` with `clip = 'off'` to plot outside the plot area and use `xlim =`  to fix the x axis to the data rather than also including the coordinates of the `annotate` call.
3. Use `plot.margin` to widen the left margin so there's room for the text.

You may need to modify the `xlim` and `x =`  arguments to get it just right.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_hline(yintercept =18,linetype="dashed", color = "red",size=1) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off',
                  xlim = c(1959.5,1962.5)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", y = 18, x = 1959.1, color = "red", label = "Actual Value") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,3), "lines"))
```

[image]

**Edit**:
You can use `\n` in the label to make the text appear on two lines.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_hline(yintercept =18,linetype="dashed", color = "red",size=1) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off',
                  xlim = c(1959.5,1962.5)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", y = 18, x = 1959.2, color = "red", label = "Actual\nValue") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,2), "lines"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_text` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=value))+geom_col()+
  geom_hline(yintercept =18,linetype="dashed", color = "red",size=1) +
  geom_text(aes(1960,18,label = 'Actual Value', vjust = -1),
           color = 'red', size = 8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ronak. That looks like a close way to do what I need. I added a new picture to show what I was looking for.
I will try to find a way to do what I needed but what you said looks like a really good second way.

Comment: I guess Ian's answer does what you want.